# Why Automated Data Driven test cases using Tosca throwing -- No suitable value found for command 'XL'

Tags: automation, tosca

I am trying to automate Salesforce instance using Tosca  ,and i used "Automated Data Driven test cases" which is simply Recording of Test cases option using the Tosca tool ,after successful recording when i tried to execute the test case by "Run in scrapbook " option ,i see error as

```
No suitable value found for command 'XL'
```

Strange because i see values got populated in Tosca Test engine of  excel generated as a result of recording[image: Error message]
here

Here is detailed error log from Tosca

```
            Tricentis.Automation.AutomationInstructions.TestActions.InvalidActionException: No suitable value found for command 'XL' ---> System.InvalidOperationException: No suitable value found for command 'XL'
            at Tricentis.Automation.AutomationInstructions.Dynamic.Values.ValueFactory.CreateValues(IParsed parsed, DataType dataType)
            at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__17`2.MoveNext()
            at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
            at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
            at Tricentis.Automation.AutomationInstructions.Dynamic.Values.ValueFactory.CreateValue(IEnumerable`1 parsedItems, DataType dataType)
            at Tricentis.Automation.AutomationInstructions.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseExpression(String expression, IEnumerable`1 tokenDefinitions, DataType dataType)
            at Tricentis.Automation.AutomationInstructions.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.GetAsValues[T](String expression, TokenDefinitionSet tokenDefinitionSet, DataType dataType)
            at Tricentis.Automation.AutomationInstructions.TestActions.AutomationObjectTestAction.get_Values()
            at Tricentis.Automation.AutomationInstructions.TestActions.AutomationObjectTextBoxTestAction.get_Values()
            at Tricentis.Automation.AutomationInstructions.TestActions.AutomationObjectTestAction.CreateSubTestActions()
            at Tricentis.Automation.AutomationInstructions.TestActions.TestAction.get_InnerActions()
            --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
            at Tricentis.Automation.AutomationInstructions.TestActions.TestAction.get_InnerActions()
            at Tricentis.Automation.AutomationInstructions.TestActions.TestAction.get_Actions()
            at Tricentis.Automation.AutomationInstructions.TestActions.TestAction.<>c.<get_ExecutableChildren>b__32_1(ITestAction testAction)
            at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator`1.MoveNext()
            at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
            at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
            at Tricentis.Automation.AutomationInstructions.TestActions.TestAction.get_ExecutableChildren()
            at Tricentis.Automation.AutomationInstructions.TestActions.TestAction.get_ConstrainingChildren()
            at Tricentis.Automation.AutomationInstructions.TestActions.AutomationObjectSearchQuery.get_TestActionConstraints()
            at Tricentis.Automation.Engines.Representations.Controllers.RepresentationController.get_ConstrainingChildTestActions()
            at Tricentis.Automation.Engines.Representations.Controllers.RepresentationController.ConstrainBySubItems(IEnumerable`1 representations)
            at Tricentis.Automation.Engines.Representations.Controllers.RepresentationController.ConstrainInternal(IEnumerable`1 representations, IModuleAttributeXParameters parameters)
            at Tricentis.Automation.Engines.Representations.Controllers.RepresentationController.Constrain(IEnumerable`1 representations)
            at Tricentis.Automation.Engines.Representations.Controllers.RepresentationController.SearchRepresentations(IAdapterController adapterController)
            at Tricentis.Automation.Engines.Representations.Controllers.RootRepresentationController.SearchRepresentation()
            at Tricentis.Automation.Engines.Representations.Controllers.RepresentationController.Search()
            at ᜁ.ᜀ(IRepresentationController A_0)
            at ᜁ.ᜁ(IRepresentationController A_0, IRepresentation& A_1)
            at ᜂ.ᜀ(IRepresentationController A_0, IRepresentation& A_1)
            at ᜁ.ᜀ()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even I got the same error message. but now solved. I tried as below:
Converted test case to template and added the Test Sheet attributes to Template by drag n drop in respective locations. If you try to run the test steps at this point then you will get this error message "No Suitable Value found for command 'XL'",
This can be avoided by "Create Template Instance" from the menu or Instantiate icon from the icon from the tool bar and then run the instantiated item in Scratch Book. It should work without any error message. I used multiple user cased and all of them worked.
Note: other observation: make sure you do not delete the Values in the cells using right click and cross mark. just get in to cell and then remove.

Answer (score 0):

You get this "No Suitable Value found for command 'XL'" when you try to run testcase from a template and not the template instance!!